# Can't enable binary logging ("index not found")

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL 5.5.41 server running on Ubuntu 14.04 that already contains several databases of data, and I would like to enable binary logging.  I want the binary logs to be placed in their own directory, `/var/log/mysqld`, which did not exist prior.  I created the directory, set its permissions to `mysql:root 0755`, and added a file to `/etc/mysql/conf.d` with the following contents:

```
[mysqld]
log_bin=/var/log/mysqld/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days=1
binlog_format=ROW
```

Unfortunately, running `service mysql restart` then failed to bring MySQL back up, and the MySQL error logs contain the message:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: File '/var/log/mysqld/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

What do I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by apparmor.  I had to add the following two lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

```
  /var/log/mysqld/ r,
  /var/log/mysqld/* rw,
```

and then run `apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` before restarting MySQL.

Comment: Problem solved with the help of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24283891/744178)